Using reducer in GEE without changing nominal scale
I loaded the MAPSPAM dataset into my Google Earth Engine asset, meaning that I have the total planted surface of each pixel for many commodities. This value is absolute and computed over 5 minutes arc degree cells.
I want to sum the total planted surface for a specific area of interest, the best choice is thus to use the "sum" reducer. but to do so I need also to provide a scale. As I don't want any rescaling to occur (as my values are absolute) I need to use 5 minutes as a scale but the scale parameter is (to my understanding) in meters which will lead to a resampling.
What should I do ?
// I agregated all the images I cannot share it. 
var image = ee.Image("projects/ldc-main-crop/assets/MAPSPAM/spam2020_v1r0_global_A_A")
var region = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0").filter(ee.Filter.eq("ADM0_NAME", "Paraguay"))
var res = image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: reducers,
  scale: image.projection().nominalScale().getInfo() // this is projectd in meters (9276m so not a acceptable value) 
});



You should never use getInfo().
You should never use nominalScale().

Any function that takes a crs and a scale, can take a regular projection object instead (and therefore you'll get the exact projection of the original object):
var res = image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: reducers,
  crs: image.projection()
});

